# TSQL: How to convert "44 days, 5:07:01" to "44:5:07:01"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to combine two different tables consisting of older and newer tickets. To make all values in the view consistent, I need to change the value of this type:

> "44 days, 5:07:01"

To:

> "44:5:07:01"

They are both stored as varchars. They are basically difference between two dates.

Also, when the difference between dates does not include "days" then the difference is shown currently as

> "5:07:01"

Which I need to convert to

> "00:05:07:01"

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves these two problems:

```
select (case when val like '% days, %'
             then left(val, charindex(' ', val)) + ':' + ltrim(right(val, 8))
             when val like '_:%'
             then '00:0' + val
             else '00:' + val
        end)
```

As with many string formatting things in SQL Server, this is quite ad hoc.  The code is not particularly flexible, but it does solve the problem for the formats in your question.

Comment: Hey Gordon - Is the syntax correct? Getting an error on the 3rd line above. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.

Answer (score 1):

**Another option**

```
Declare @YourTable table (YourCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('44 days, 5:07:01'),
('4 days, 5:07:01'),
('5:07:01')

Select right(IIF(charindex(' d',YourCol)=0,'00',rtrim(left('0'+YourCol,3))),2)
       +':'+right('0'+replace(' '+YourCol,' ','0'),8)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)
44:05:07:01
04:05:07:01
00:05:07:01
```